# Cual es la mejor forma de guardar el resultado de un inner join y llamar los resultados por un metodo

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

Tengo dos tablas inventario y producto, en producto tengo unos datos y en inventario otros, están ligadas por el numero de producto. En mi código tengo dos objetos que tienen por atributos las columnas de cada tabla. Hasta ahí nada nuevo.

Generalmente, cuando consulto una tabla de un solo tipo de objetos guardo los resultados en un ArrayList del tipo objeto (producto, inventario, etc), El asunto es que hare una consulta que me muestre datos de ambas tablas con un join, pero no se como guardar los resultados. En resumen seria una lista multdimensional que es la primera vez que realizo.

Alguien que se apiade de mi!!!!
Pd Creo que no tengo problemas con la consulta por que jala..
Mi objeto Producto

```
public class Producto implements Serializable {
private int Num_Producto;
private String NombreProd;
private String Clasificacion;
private float Precio_Venta;
private float Precio_Compra;
```

Mi Objeto Inventario

```
public class Inventario implements Serializable {
private int Num_Inventario;
private int Producto_Num;
private int Cantidad;
private int EmpleadoSrv;
private String FechaCad;
private String Lote;
```

Mi intento de metodo

```
public static ArrayList ***no se como va ****ConsultarProductobyInventario() {
       PreparedStatement st = null;        
    try {
        String SQL = "SELECT producto.NombreProd, producto.Clasificacion, producto.Precio_Venta, inventario.Cantidad, inventario.Lote FROM producto join inventario on  inventario.Producto_Num = producto.Num_Producto;";
        st= conexion().prepareStatement(SQL);
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<Producto> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        Producto prod;
        while(res.next()){ //aqui menos!!!!
            prod=new Producto();
            prod.setNum_Producto(res.getInt("num_producto"));
            prod.setNombreProd(res.getString("nombreprod"));
            prod.setClasificacion(res.getString("clasificacion"));
            prod.setPrecio_Venta(res.getInt("precio_venta"));
            prod.setPrecio_Compra(res.getInt("precio_compra"));

            lista.add(prod);
        }
        //st.close();
        return lista;
    } catch (SQLException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(EmpresaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que veo usas JDBC a pelo (sin usar Hibernates ni otro framework). Lo mas facil es que crees una clase , que herede, por ejemplo producto, a la que le puedes llamar InventarioProducto y luego le añades los campos de Inventario ;-)

```
public class InventarioProducto extends Producto
{
...
private int Num_Inventario;
private int Cantidad;
private int EmpleadoSrv;
private String FechaCad;
private String Lote;
}
```

Y en esa clase metes los resultados de tu query.

Comment: Gracias @chuchip acabo de poner en practica tu respuesta y funciono, desgraciadamente es mi proyecto terminal y no se me permite usar ningun framework, raro y poco real, pero asi son los requerimientos....